# Template function pointer

Tags: c++

Suppose we have the general function pointer:

```
template <class ArgT, class RetT, class F>
struct A {
    F f;
public:
    A(F f) : f(f) {}

    RetT operator()(ArgT arg) { return f(arg); }
};
```

Why does this work?

```
template <class ArgT, class RetT, class F>
class B {
    A<ArgT, RetT, F> test;
};
```

... and this not ?

```
class C {
    template <class ArgT, class RetT, class F>
    A<ArgT, RetT, F> test;
};
```

error C3857: 'C::test': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed

I need to define a class like in last example (class C), how can I do that?

Comment: because it doesn't make sense. how can you use it and how can compile generate code for it?

Comment: `sizeof(C)` would be infinite ^_^

Comment: Thank you all for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because variables can't have template. In fact just classes and functions can have template.

*Edit: As Alan Stokes said, in C++14, variables also can have template.*